# Armature replecate "preserve volume" without using the option

Tags: animation

I am making a mod for Risk of Rain 2 and the option "preserve volume" on the armature would greatly increase the quality of the animation.
Bad thing is, Risk of Rain 2/Unity does not support that option in the armature. Is there a way to recreate the effect of that option, without actually using it?
If its a modifier it has to be one I can apply at the end.

Comment: You need to be looking at Unity, not at Blender.  The keywords you're looking for is "quaternion skinning".  Quick Google got me https://forum.unity.com/threads/dual-quaternion-skinning-for-unity.501245/ , free, untested.  If you can't change the code of the Unity game you're modding, you're probably out of luck-- you're at the mercy of whatever the designers chose to implement, which probably does not include what you want.  (Outside of the absurd "make a bone for every vertex" kind of options.)